# How to get the effective URL from \Goutte\Client?

Tags: php, symfony, goutte

I am developing a webscraper using \Goutte\Client and i need to get the effective URL after doing a request. I am doing the following to instantiate \Goutte\Client:

```php
new \Goutte\Client(\Symfony\Component\HttpClient\HttpClient::create([
...
]);
```

So the Symfony stack including BrowserKit and CurlHttpClient is used for all this stuff ... as far as i can see by grepping through the Symfony sourcecode is, that in theory i should be able to get the information i need if i could somehow gain access to `CurlResponse->getInfo()`. However, i am unable to figure out how to do this. Everything (request/response) is wrapped inside GoutteClient and BrowserKit and as far as i can see they won't let me access the CurlResponse directly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can extend GoutteClient if what you're after isn't private or is passed in the constructor. Looking at the class, it's just extending `Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\HttpBrowser` anyways. I'm guessing this is more about dependency management than Goutte offering features.

Comment: Lol ... you are right - regarding GoutteClient, apparently i got tricked by old tutorials; i could also directly use Browserkit. However, extending isn't that easy. CurlResponse get's wrapped in doRequest and i can't just overwrite doRequest because some methods needed in there are private. I also cannot extend CurlHttpClient because it's final. Maybe i could develop some proxy-class for CurlHttpClient, but this all seems way to complicated for such a simple requirement ... :(